# Queues or Dictionaries for shared ressources in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have two threads with while loops in them. The first process data that the second needs to elaborate in parallel. I need to share a variable.

let's introduce dummy input:

```py
data = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

My first class of Thread:

```py
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.queue = queue
        _download = {}
        

    def run(self):
        i = 0

        while True:
            _download[i] = next(data)
            self.queue.put(next(data))

            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
```

My second class of Thread:

```py
class Thread2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.queue.get()
            
            time.sleep(3)
```

with the `main` method:

```py
q = Queue(maxsize=10)
t = Thread1(q)
s = Thread2(q)
t.start()
s.start()
```

I illustratedthe two alternatives for the case. I can access queue variable from the second Thread but I also want that the second Thread access the dictionary.

1. what can I do to access also the dictionary from Thread2?
2. for which choice should I opt?